# solving radical equation

Tags: radicals, radical-equations

$$\sqrt{3x+1} - \sqrt{6-x} +3x^2-14x-8=0 $$

I tried :   $3x+1 = a $ , $6-x=b $ and tried to make $ 3x^2-14x-8 $ to be in term of $a$ and $b$, I'm unable to solve it so far.

but I know the answer is $ x = 5 $ by trying to guess because   $ 6-x \geq 0 $ 
and I checked the integer from $ 0$ to $6$.

I can't think of a way to solve this properly without guessing the answer.

Comment: This is an exercise at high school level...and it looks like it was designed by a sadist teacher to torture his(her) students. Unless there is a slick trick (like saying we want all the integer solutions, if any, of the equation...though in that case it'd be a little too trivial), I can't see an easy way to tackle this monster.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm having a rough time learning math right now because sometime I don't know what's been thrown at me is too hard so i should skip or i'm just missing something lol.

Comment: I think this exercise is extremely difficult for a standard high school student...

Comment: It is possible to move the $\sqrt{6-x}$ to one side, then square both sides. Afterwards, there will be one radical, which may be isolated, and then the entire equation can be squared again... for a grand total of an 8th degree polynomial. Good luck.

Comment: "I can't think of a way to solve this properly without guessing the answer."  Why do you think there is one?

Comment: @fleablood they said they found $x=5$...

Comment: @KhunpolJermsiri Is this the original question you have been asked or .. ?

Comment: Just a far shot, but you wouldn't happen to be allowed to use graphing calculators as your reasoning?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  " they said they found x=5"  By guessing....

Answer (score 2):

I've done some reverse-factoring ( don't know if this is the right word or not ) knowing the answer is 5

so i got

$(x-5)\left [(\frac{\sqrt{3x+1}-4}{(x-5)})-(\frac{\sqrt{6-x}-1}{(x-5)})+(\frac{(3x+1)(x-5)}{(x-5)})  \right ] = 0 $

$(x-5)\left [(\frac{3}{(\sqrt{3x+1}+4)})+(\frac{1}{(\sqrt{6-x}+1)})+(3x+1)  \right ] = 0 $
the right bracket is always more than $0$

i guess this is one way to do it lol.

Comment: What for? If you already guessed that $\;x=5\;$ is an answer (and not the only one...), you can simply substitute $\;x=5\;$ in the equation and verify... And no: of course this cannot possibly one way to do it as it requires you **first** to guess a solution...! And BTW, you're left with a factor you have no idea how to solve...!

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm trying to see what the question want me to do by looking at this form, but i think the comment above might be true, this question might be too hard for me. I can see that (3x+1)(x-5) can be subsitute to a,-(b-1)  i'll try this later though. the right factor i can left it out because it's alway more than 0.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=3x^2-14x-8$ is strictly increasing, for $x\geq -7/3$ and the function
$g(x)=\sqrt{3x+1}-\sqrt{6-x}$ is defined for $x\in[-{1\over 3},6]$ and is also increasing.

So equation $f(x)+g(x)=0$ has at most one solution. Can you guess it?

---

Edit: $6-x$ is decreasing, so is $\sqrt{6-x}$ but then $-\sqrt{6-x}$ is increasing. Since $\sqrt{3x+1}$ is increasing and the sum of incrasing function is increasing, $g(x)$ must be increasing.

Comment: How can one guess a correct number from infinite numbers?

Comment: How can you tell, in both cases (but particularly in the case of $g(x)$), in an elementary way, that we have increasing functions?

Comment: Trying some integer...

Comment: "How can one guess a correct number from infinite numbers? "  Well the OP somehow did......

Comment: That is not an acceptable, imo, way to proceed. The next time (s)he faces aproblem with a rational non-integer solution he won't be able then to do it...

Comment: @fleablood But he literally need a secure method, that is why he asked the question in first place.

Comment: Well, yeah.... but I think this answer hones a bit more how to use calculus to verify that there is only one solution and it is in a range with trial and error on integers will fine tune.  There may not be a method of solving but such a question for equations *with* guessable integer or simple rational solutions are fair.  (kinda... I personally don't like them, but I can't say I haven't seen them often enough).

Comment: They are usualy proposed to see if a student understands basic concepts of elementary analysis

Comment: But how can I come with an answer in the first place, let alone verify it by analysis. Here I agree one can do guess, but if the domain span across hundred of integers? This method of guessing fail miserably

Comment: But why would someone create such a problem/equation? With what purpose?

Comment: Because [the teacher might be a sadist that enjoys torturing students](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264416/solving-radical-equation#comment6712765_3264416).

Comment: I ain't sure whether this is the problem they originally asked or whether while solving the original problem, he came up with this equation.

Comment: "How many solutions does this equation have? Find them all within intervals of length 1." is a fair question.  There need not be a method.

Comment: "but if the domain span across hundred of integers? This method of guessing fail miserably "  And.... ?  No one ever said this method was a *good* or practical one.

Comment: Well, I'm not with you @fleablood. Can you offer better one? And as I said, it is just to practice elementary analysis